Waiting for input from user using threads
I'm writing a client-server trivia game in python.
In the game, i want the user to have an option to enter input as long as he is playing.
Once the game ends (someone has won), he can no longer enter input.
So in my code I'm running in a while loop that waits for input while the player is playing.
My problem: If is_playing changes from another part of my program while the function is waiting for input, I need a way to check the value of is_playing periodically.
In the provided code, when is_playing changes from the outside to False, listener_thread will never stop running so main thread will never pass the listener_thread.join() action.
def __input_listener(self, input_queue):
    while True:
        try:
            message = input()
            input_queue.put(message)
        except EOFError:
            break

def __handle_user_inputs(self):

    input_queue = queue.Queue()
    listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.__input_listener, args=(input_queue,))
    listener_thread.start()

    while self.is_alive and self.is_playing:
        try:

            message = input_queue.get(timeout=0.5)
            self.__send_message(message)

        except queue.Empty:
            # No input received, loop back and check conditions
            if not self.is_playing:
                break

    listener_thread.join()  # Clean up the thread


Please check - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  -
While this is an answearable problem, it will be much harder if the one answering it has to create the boilerplate details for the solution to work - including import statements and class declarations.

Now, coming to your problem - this is not that easy to resolve - once input() is called, it will block its thread until an end of line arrives on sys.stdin (and you can't write to that stream from within the process).
Some libraries feature an  "asynchronous" version of input - you can get an asyncio loop running in a separate thread.  "terminedia" is one such library featuring an ainput() that could possibly work for your case.
